# Display table header and table data in separate partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Actually I want to display a common header in my view with different set of data. I have a view with multiple tables each table has same header. I want to move it into a partial or place it before calling the partial for table data

Comment: it will be better if you can put your view files here

Comment: This can be done easily. There's no trick to it. It's like any other partial. What is your specific question? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Show your code what you have done and explain what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create file with this view, for example **_header.html.erb**, and in other partial you might call this partial:

```
<%= render "header" %>
```

or if you want pass any variables:

```
<%= render "header", locals: {title: @title} >
```

That code call the partial from app/views/_header.html.erb.

Comment: I wouldn't put the partial file right under `views`. If it's used my multiple views, then perhaps a `common` folder under views.

Answer (score 0):

view/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= render '/layouts/commen' %>
```

create one file in layout floder

_commen.html.erb

add your all code here

Answer (score 0):

If your action name is action_1 you have `action_1.html.erb` then you need a partial for every table or one partial for all table.
If you have one partial for all tables then this partial should be render with data that it needs:

```
def action_1
  render locals: {title: 'Title', table_1_data: table_1_data, table_2_data: table_2_data, table_3_data: table_3_data}
end
```

name of partial is `_tables_data.html.erb`.
`action_1.html.erb`:

```
<h1><%= title %></h1>
<%= render partial: 'tables_data', locals: {table_1_data: table_1_data, table_2_data: table_2_data, table_3_data: table_3_data} %>
```